# Google action request for grant_type=refresh_token does not update conversation object with new access token

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, actions-on-google

I'm developing a google action which is configured for account linking using Linking Type: "OAuth" / "Authorization code". The OAuth2 authorization server functions are hosted in the same place as the linked business application server, so I have full visibility of the traffic in both regards.

The initial linking process works perfectly every time; however, a problem arises when the original access token expires, and a new one is requested grant_type=refresh_token. Included below are the sanitized log contents from our server's execution logic generated by invocation of the google action using Actions Console "Test" simulator, *after the original access token has expired*. As expected, the google action first requests a new access token by calling the Token Url with grant_type=refresh_token. Our server then returns content to the caller
shown below under **SmartAssistOAuthToken: result=** as

> {"expires_in":600,"token_type":"Bearer","access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.xxxx.5XRFvkrBr7PCfyyqSMW1nNJBI0EceQgFrMA-6I04sQA"}

Having received the new token, the Google action proceeds to the main intent / webhook handler which contains a REST request back to the same server to retrieve some information about the current user's account.
This is shown below as: **>********> 2021/07/15 12:16:18 (-05:00) - /cgi-bin/w2w.dll/sa_anon?cmd=login...**

```
>********> 2021/07/15 12:16:15 (-05:00) - /cgi-bin/w2w.dll/AoG_token?
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SmartAssistOAuthToken: contentfields=
grant_type=refresh_token
refresh_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.xxxx.65URfGpCL4s9nZiUc2pvYRZydK6jKanI5DZAZm04BtM
client_id=xxxx
client_secret=xxxx
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SmartAssistOAuthToken: result= (...using 600 to speed things up a bit)
{"expires_in":600,"token_type":"Bearer","access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.xxxx.5XRFvkrBr7PCfyyqSMW1nNJBI0EceQgFrMA-6I04sQA"}

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>********> 2021/07/15 12:16:18 (-05:00) - /cgi-bin/w2w.dll/sa_anon?cmd=login&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.xxxx.FfUGlS71IaIU3LdkiJtUKfBBZwjSaN5D0s1ECpzxop4
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SmartAssistLogin: QueryFields=
cmd=login
access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.xxxx.FfUGlS71IaIU3LdkiJtUKfBBZwjSaN5D0s1ECpzxop4
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidAccessTokenInfo: AccessToken's JWT has expired.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SmartAssistError: Error={"error_uri":"https:xxxx","error_description":"Invalid authorization credential.","error":"invalid_request"}
```

At the end of the "login" REST request is the access token which I read from **conv.session.params.bearerToken**, and then add to the url.

> /cgi-bin/w2w.dll/sa_anon?cmd=login&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.xxxx.FfUGlS71IaIU3LdkiJtUKfBBZwjSaN5D0s1ECpzxop4

However, the value provided by conv.session.params.bearerToken (**eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.xxxx.FfUGlS71IaIU3LdkiJtUKfBBZwjSaN5D0s1ECpzxop4**) is not the new one returned to the refresh token request (**eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.xxxx.5XRFvkrBr7PCfyyqSMW1nNJBI0EceQgFrMA-6I04sQA**). As such, my server returns an error for the request because the original token is no longer valid / expired.

The entire (sanitized) incoming conv object is as follows, wherein all references to bearerToken are the same recently expired token:

```
{
    "overwrite": false,
    "digested": false,
    "request": {
        "handler": {
            "name": "main"
        },
        "intent": {
            "name": "actions.intent.MAIN",
            "params": {},
            "query": "Talk to work assistant"
        },
        "scene": {
            "name": "Main",
            "slotFillingStatus": "UNSPECIFIED",
            "slots": {}
        },
        "session": {
            "id": "ABwppHFsSDza7b0R74-kOOBCudqHWhrjIMma8mnaLjTDFg55O68MIjBIPRgaSEyAH31RPOJGG9VhrIl283LWY6xXZsw",
            "params": {},
            "typeOverrides": [],
            "languageCode": ""
        },
        "user": {
            "locale": "en-US",
            "params": {
                "AccountLinkingSlot": "LINKED",
                "bearerToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.xxxx.FfUGlS71IaIU3LdkiJtUKfBBZwjSaN5D0s1ECpzxop4",

                },
            "accountLinkingStatus": "LINKED",
            "verificationStatus": "VERIFIED",
            "packageEntitlements": [],
            "gaiamint": "",
            "permissions": [],
            "lastSeenTime": "2021-07-15T16:15:48Z"
        },
        "home": {
            "params": {}
        },
        "device": {
            "capabilities": ["SPEECH", "RICH_RESPONSE", "LONG_FORM_AUDIO"],
            "timeZone": {
                "id": "America/Chicago",
                "version": ""
            }
        }
    },
    "headers": {
        "host": "us-central1-work-assistant-b9910.cloudfunctions.net",
        "user-agent": "Google-ActionsOnGoogle/1.0",
        "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "forwarded": "for=\"66.249.83.57\";proto=https",
        "function-execution-id": "zn46t5q3mkfr",
        "google-actions-api-version": "3",
        "google-assistant-signature": "xxxx",
        "traceparent": "00-6b5c4d0aa670f39009910ec1f7e908ee-2abd7ee7886b286d-00",
        "x-appengine-country": "ZZ",
        "x-appengine-default-version-hostname": "d1c092144ed53556ap-tp.appspot.com",
        "x-appengine-https": "on",
        "x-appengine-request-log-id": "60f06d6200ff0c6741e353b4fb0001737e6431633039323134346564353335353661702d7470000133343061346661353033613135323331626363326539303833646463386639313a310001010c",
        "x-appengine-timeout-ms": "599998",
        "x-appengine-user-ip": "66.249.83.57",
        "x-cloud-trace-context": "6b5c4d0aa670f39009910ec1f7e908ee/3079757253082556525",
        "x-forwarded-for": "66.249.83.57",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
        "connection": "close"
    },
    "handler": {
        "name": "main"
    },
    "intent": {
        "name": "actions.intent.MAIN",
        "query": "Talk to work assistant",
        "params": {}
    },
    "scene": {
        "name": "Main",
        "slotFillingStatus": "UNSPECIFIED",
        "slots": {},
        "next": {}
    },
    "session": {
        "id": "ABwppHFsSDza7b0R74-kOOBCudqHWhrjIMma8mnaLjTDFg55O68MIjBIPRgaSEyAH31RPOJGG9VhrIl283LWY6xXZsw",
        "params": {
            "AccountLinkingSlot": "LINKED",
            "bearerToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.xxxx.FfUGlS71IaIU3LdkiJtUKfBBZwjSaN5D0s1ECpzxop4",
        },
        "typeOverrides": [],
        "languageCode": ""
    },
    "user": {
        "locale": "en-US",
        "params": {
            "AccountLinkingSlot": "LINKED",
            "bearerToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.xxxx.FfUGlS71IaIU3LdkiJtUKfBBZwjSaN5D0s1ECpzxop4",
        },
        "accountLinkingStatus": "LINKED",
        "verificationStatus": "VERIFIED",
        "packageEntitlements": [],
        "gaiamint": "",
        "permissions": [],
        "lastSeenTime": "2021-07-15T16:15:48Z"
    },
    "device": {
        "capabilities": ["SPEECH", "RICH_RESPONSE", "LONG_FORM_AUDIO"],
        "currentLocation": {},
        "timeZone": {
            "id": "America/Chicago",
            "version": ""
        }
    },
    "home": {
        "params": {}
    },
    "expected": {},
    "context": {},
    "prompt": {
        "override": false
    },
    "_internal": {
        "promptSet": false,
        "orig": {
            "scene": {
                "name": "Main",
                "slotFillingStatus": "UNSPECIFIED",
                "slots": {},
                "next": {}
            },
            "session": {
                "id": "ABwppHFsSDza7b0R74-kOOBCudqHWhrjIMma8mnaLjTDFg55O68MIjBIPRgaSEyAH31RPOJGG9VhrIl283LWY6xXZsw",
                "params": {},
                "typeOverrides": [],
                "languageCode": ""
            },
            "user": {
                "locale": "en-US",
                "params": {
                    "AccountLinkingSlot": "LINKED",
                    "bearerToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.xxxx.FfUGlS71IaIU3LdkiJtUKfBBZwjSaN5D0s1ECpzxop4",
                },
                "accountLinkingStatus": "LINKED",
                "verificationStatus": "VERIFIED",
                "packageEntitlements": [],
                "gaiamint": "",
                "permissions": [],
                "lastSeenTime": "2021-07-15T16:15:48Z"
            },
            "home": {
                "params": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The relevant google action webhook code looks something like this:

```
const {conversation,
       Suggestion,
       Simple,
       Card,
       Image
    } = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = conversation();
...
const getAccessToken = (conv) => {
  return conv.session.params.bearerToken;
};
...
app.handle('main', async conv => {
    ...
    console.log("main: >>>>>>>>>>>>>> conv=",JSON.stringify(conv));
    ...
    if (conv.user.verificationStatus !== 'VERIFIED') {
        conv.add('Sorry, your account is not verified yet so you cannot be here.');
        return;
    }
    ...
    await getRemoteData(`${getFullredirectpath()}sa_anon?cmd=login&access_token=${getAccessToken(conv)}`)
      .then((response) => {
        (success handling...)
      })
      .catch((err) => { 
        (Error handling...)
       return;
    });
    ...
}
```

This problem doesn't happen every time a token is refreshed, but it does happen frequently, and seemingly more so, the longer the time between sessions. I can almost always count on it to happen overnight.

Comment: Additional information: Seems that this problem might be specific to the Test/Simulator; i.e. I have not found a case where this occurs using my smart phone. Also, when it does fail, I find that the conversation object is missing the "authorization":"Bearer ..." header.